# Converting from full to sparse matrices

Tags: matlab

I have an adjacency weight matrix of a graph. I want to call the bellman ford algorithm of the matlabbgl libaray. How can I convert the matrix to a sparse format?

Comment: maybe call [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) on it?

Comment: you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there) and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 4):

Converting Full to Sparse

You can convert a full matrix to sparse storage using the sparse function with a single argument.

```
S = sparse(A)
```

For example

```
A = [ 0   0   0   5
      0   2   0   0
      1   3   0   0
      0   0   4   0];
S = sparse(A)
```

produces

```
S =

   (3,1)        1
   (2,2)        2
   (3,2)        3
   (4,3)        4
   (1,4)        5
```

The printed output lists the nonzero elements of S, together with their row and column indices. The elements are sorted by columns, reflecting the internal data structure.
You can convert a sparse matrix to full storage using the full function, provided the matrix order is not too large. For example A = full(S) reverses the example conversion.
Converting a full matrix to sparse storage is not the most frequent way of generating sparse matrices. If the order of a matrix is small enough that full storage is possible, then conversion to sparse storage rarely offers significant savings.